# How do I efficiently query ldap with a list of uids?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I know I can query ldap with a huge and statement like so

```
(&(uid='uid-1')(uid='uid-2') ... (uid='uid-nth'))
```

Is there a better way?

The output is fine, and there is no problem just looking for better ways to query.

Thanks in advance for the response, and I hope this is not to trivial of a question

Comment: why you need info from many users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually shouldn't return anything as you are using an  and `&` instead of and or `|`.

If you are using *ldapsearch* from the command line you can usually pass in a filter file with the `-f` flag. This way you can pass in any many different filters, 1 per line, to the same command. The output will be similar to what you have now but each will be submitted as a different search to the directory server. In your case the file would look like...

```
uid=uid-1
uid=uid-2
uid=uid-n
```